# Установка слайдера tiny slider?

Tags: vue.js

Друзья как подключить слайдер?
Читал форумы не у одного у меня позникли проблемы (webpack/vue)

https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider#install

Comment: А какие именно проблемы и что же именно на форумах удалось вычитать - говорить не нужно, лучше ссылку на инструкцию... Или просто вопрос для избранных, для своих?:)

Comment: Можеш решить за меня проблема в webpack - tiny-slider.js?2feb:180 Can't find .slider.
2) Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: у Вас мало подробностей. я подключал разными способами, инициировал как присваивание свойству, заданному в дата.все нормально работает, пока не изменил адреса картинок. но это уже другая тема. в описаниях issue по указанному адресу много полезного имеется. ответ такой, поскольку по существу не на что отвечать. но перечисленное мне помогло. возможно вот тут будет полезное. https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider/issues/20

Comment: возможно вот эта обертка будет Вам или тем кто нацйдет этот вопрос полезна, если еще не решили проболему. https://github.com/viktorlarsson/vue-tiny-slider